# ComponentReferenceCapture update in blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

In a blazor sample, I am using a RenderFragment to update the elements dynamically and also captured the component reference for each updates. While capturing elements initially, it captures the component reference properly. When I update a component, it retains the older componentReference. Component reference did not update properly.

**Index.razor**

```
@page "/"

<button @onclick="AddContent">1st Update</button>
<button @onclick="AddSecondContent">2nd Update</button>
<button @onclick="CheckContent">Check Update</button>
@DataContent

@code {
    RenderFragment DataContent { get; set; }
    List<Counter> CounterReference = new List<Counter>();
    void AddContent()
    {
        DataContent = (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RenderTreeBuilder builder) =>
        {
            int seq = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                builder.OpenComponent<Counter>(seq++);
                builder.AddComponentReferenceCapture(seq++, ins => { CounterReference.Add((Counter)ins); });
                builder.CloseComponent();
            }

        };
        InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }

    void AddSecondContent()
    {
        CounterReference.Clear();
        DataContent = (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RenderTreeBuilder builder) =>
        {
            int seq = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                builder.OpenComponent<Counter>(seq++);
                builder.AddComponentReferenceCapture(seq++, ins => { CounterReference.Add((Counter)ins); });
                builder.CloseComponent();
            }

        };
        InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }

    void CheckContent()
    {
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

**counter.razor**

```
@page "/counter"

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    public void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

In the above sample, I have updated the **DataContent** initially, I am getting Count of ***CounterReference*** as 3. After this, I cleared a CounterReference and I updated the **DataContent**. In the second case, I am rendering 2 Counter component which rendered in the DOM properly. But I am getting Count of ***CounterReference*** as 0. In the second update, If I did not clear the ***CounterReference***, I am getting its value as 3. Such that it retains its previous value. I am expecting this value to be 2.

What I am doing wrong with this?

Comment: First this is quite an ambitious way to create components and very easy to get wrong. The biggest mistake most people make is to use a variable to do this `seq++`
See the section "Sequence Number" in this [article on RenderTreeBuilder](https://chrissainty.com/building-components-via-rendertreebuilder/) by [Chris Sainty](https://chrissainty.com/), and [Steve Sanderson's explanation](https://gist.github.com/SteveSandersonMS/ec232992c2446ab9a0059dd0fbc5d0c3) and should use a static, incremented count. Otherwise the Blazor renderer will get confused about what element you're updating.

Comment: What @Quango said, but additionally, when you render in a loop, always use the `@key` directive to uniquely identify what you are rendering - relying on the "sequence" is not going to guarantee that the diffing algorithm always captures when to drop/create new objects. What is probably happening here is that Blazor thinks you have initially created 3 Counters, then just removed one (#3) - but it can hang on to the other two and as it already generated references for those, you don't get new ones.

Comment: Out of interest, is there a reason you are using the `RenderTreeBuilder`? What are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: @Quango Thanks. Your suggestion is working.